# Exact::extract, Error: [names<-] incorrect number of names

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster file from https://spei.csic.es/spei_database/#map_name=spei01#map_position=1439.
It is a monthly data for 120 years and it has 1440 bands.

I need to extract the annual data. Using a national level shape file that is downloaded from GADM (and it is 4GB so I cannot share it here), I ran the following commands

```
gpkg_admin0 = sf::read_sf('gadm_410-levels.gpkg', layer = 'ADM_0') 
data = raster::raster("spei01.nc")
exactextractr::exact_extract(data, gpkg_admin0, fun = "mean")
```

but this error came up.

```
Error: [names<-] incorrect number of names
```

the band of the data is 1 (out of 1440) which means the data is for "1901-01-16". If I change the band number the same error comes up. I do not know how to solve this error.

In case you need the shape file, you can download from https://gadm.org/download_country.html.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: See https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/623#issuecomment-1114314479